# QGIS 2.6 Curriculum Redo?

Tags: qgis, education

We are in the middle of creating GIS curriculum based on QGIS. When we started in June 2014 it was still 2.2, then 2.4, now 2.6.  You think it's worth returning to step 1 and begin again in 2.6?

Comment: Most of the concepts haven't changed from 2.2 to 2.6 - except for the data browser. It should be a matter of redoing screen shots for the newer version and ensuring you're using the correct menus then including new functionality that you may wish to include.

Comment: Depending on how you define 'curriculum', I might also suggest trying to make things as software agnostic as possible if you aren't already. If you've chosen QGIS for the practical/exercise portion of things that's fine and of course you do have to keep things up to date no matter what software you use. But if the lessons/concepts are independent of software it should mean less revision is needed when things change. Sort of a 'are you teaching GIS or teaching QGIS' kind of thing.

Comment: For curriculum (in US), consider researching [the one freely available from GeoAcademy](http://foss4geo.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 2):

To me this comes down what you are doing in the course and what features you use. Having to update manuals is a downside of a quick release process, however this is a known issue and we are planning on making LTR releases so you can target those and keep manuals stable for their life. You can read about it more [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/pull/6/files?short_path=fc13396#diff-fc1339674caa29ca5f9a0a9887ca4489).

Most of the core stuff is still in the same place, but it should be noted that there have been a lot of improvements between each version, including new rendering engine in 2.4. and legend tree in 2.6.

I will also note that there have been minor (depends on how you define minor) UI changes between each version in our on going effort to make the software better for users. Normally we try and leave things as is but sometimes things just have to change.  I don't suspect it will trip many people up things are normally moved to a better place.